# Word document changes after saving as pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

**When I save my Word document as PDF, the word document changes.**

The changes which happen are:

*insertion of an extra table, and change in margin on that same page*.

- The pdf looks like the word document as it looks *after* I have saved it as a pdf.
- The word-document is in .docx-format but the same thing happens if I first save it as .doc format, and then try to save as pdf.
- This only happens with this particular word document.

---

**This is what the document looks like before I save as pdf:**

[image: before]

---

**This is what the document looks like *after* I've saved as a pdf:**

[image: after]

The difference is that a table is inserted in the word-document, after it has been saved as PDF.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the document somewhere for testing?

Comment: I'm interested in unexplained fact, if you can still remember it: what is the origin of the extra table? I mean, the table was originally created by someone. At the time when you started PDF conversion, was it on the clipboard? Or was it already hidden in the document?

Comment: @miroxlav no sorry can't remember exactly. I don't think the table was in the clipboard, but I think it did exist in the document on one of the last pages.

Comment: did you show all hidden texts? May be the table was there. It's just hidden

Comment: Note that there is a large class of printers with native PDF drivers (they were usually expensive). This means that you can install the free drivers for one of those printers (without purchasing it); then in the printer setup you can force it to print to PDF file... and voila you have the option _to print into a PDF file_. It worked a long time ago with the shared laser printer since they started appearing (e.g. big HP with multiple trays that can be loaded with several reams of paper at a time...). You should be able to easily find something compliant with your OS. The PDF is really Portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say what method you use to create the PDF other than saving as, but if the Word document is being changed, you likely have some type of plugin being used, like Adobe Acrobat.

If the plugin is having trouble with this one particular document, '*printing to PDF*' instead of '*saving as PDF*' should resolve your issue, but I have seen where an older, no longer supported version of Adobe Acrobat will output the same thing when 'printing to PDF' that the plugin did, so you might have to use *Microsoft Print to PDF* or other method of printing to PDF that is different from your plugin.

If this document is only the first exposure to the problem and you find that the output is getting changed regularly, the office plugin from the PDF software you use is the most likely culprit and should be uninstalled/replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I used previous versions of Word and after saving the book file to both Word PDF, I also met "Save the file.doc?" again when I exit, while I did not see obvious changes in both the Word and PDF files.
I suggest saving the document in DOC format only before saving it as PDF. And then  simply closing, in order to avoid any hidden change made by the PDF software.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. In my case this was due to messed up cross references. Exporting to pdf triggers an document wide update of all fields. That resulted in the changes. It was not caused by the save as pdf.

I removed the faulty cross references and added them again, and my problems were gone.

Answer (score 0):

convert it using some word to pdf converter. The built in converter of Microsoft Word is not working properly for some documents (I experienced some issues). You can use free converter doPDF downloadable from http://www.dopdf.com. After installing this will adds a printer to your printers list. So you simply print your document and your pdf is ready.